# Что означает "мо" в словах камо, тамо, семо, овамо?

Tags: этимология

Что означает вторая часть слов камо, тамо, семо, овамо, инамо, онамо, мимо, единамо, обоямо, яможе, аможе и т.п.? Перечисленные слова относятся к наречиям места, может ли в этой связи часть "мо" означать сокращение от слова "место"?

Answer (score 3):

Нет, назвать  сокращением, видимо, всё-таки нельзя, но -м- это суффикс со значением места, а -о     - окончание.

Этимологическая справка к наречию там:

> Общеслав. Соврем. форма — из тамо, суф. производного (ср. устар. камо,
>   семо, овамо) от указат. местоим. тъ, та, то (см. тот). Безударный
>   конечный о (тамо > там) отпал, ср. пусть, теперь и т. п.

https://etymological.academic.ru/5080/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC

> § 266. Первообразные наречия образовывались, во-первых, от
>   местоименных корней къ (ко, ку), тъ, (то, ту), сь (сё, сю), вьс- с
>   помощью суффиксов -уд- (-юд-) и-окончаний -а, -ы, -у; к ним относились
>   наречия куда (куды), туда (туды), сюда (сюды), вьсюду. Во-вторых, от
>   тех же местоименных корней наречия образовывались также с суф. -гд- и
>   окончаниями - ѣ, -а: къгдѣ, къгда, тъгда (а также от корней ин- (иной)
>   и ов-: иногда, овогда); с суф. -д- и окончанием -ѣ: къдѣ, индѣ,
>   вьсьдѣ; **с суф. -м- и окончанием -о: семо, тамо, овамо**; с суф. -ли:
>   коли (а также от корней к, кже: кли, кжели).

http://xn--e1akbokk.com/russkogo-yazyika-istoriya/narechiya-istoriya-obrazovaniya-50091.html